# How to write numbers range by using dots in math mode by using siunitx package?

Tags: math-mode, equations, siunitx, numrange

I have the following equation:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:General:3:body:equation}
m_i \ddot{\vec{R_i}}=G m_i \sum_{\substack {j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^n \frac{m_j}{R_{i j}^3} \left(\vec{R}_j -\vec{R}_i \right) + \vec{F}^*_i \qquad i=1,...,n
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to write `i=1,...,n` by using the `siunitx` package?
I read the documentation but it reports the form `1 to n`

Comment: Use `\dots`, `\cdots` or `\ldots` instead of three dots. Numerical ranges are provided by `siunitx` but it is usually an overkill IMO. You could do the following: `i = \numrange[range-phrase={,\cdots,}]{1}{100}` but the same can be achieved just by simple expression: `i = 1,\dots,100`. However, if you deal with units, then `siunitx` is much more handy, e.g. `\qtyrange[
    range-units=repeat,  % instead of repeat
    range-phrase={ to },
]{1}{100}{\kJ\per\mol}`